# Infinite loop when disabling input X if input Y gets value and viceversa in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form with angular2.
I have two text input elements, and each have its own valueChange function.
In this, the other input is disabled if there is a non emtpy value, and enabled otherwise, and this triggers a change event in the other input, generating an infinite loop. How can I solve that?

Code is like this:

```
this.myForm.get('inputX').valueChages.subscribe(val => {
 if(val && val.trim().length > 0) {
  this.myForm.get('inputY').disable(); // this triggers a change in inputY
 } else {
  this.myForm.get('inputY').enable(); // this triggers a change in inputY
 }
})
this.myForm.get('inputY').valueChages.subscribe(val => {
 if(val && val.trim().length > 0) {
  this.myForm.get('inputX').disable(); // this triggers a change in inputX
 } else {
  this.myForm.get('inputX').enable(); // this triggers a change in inputX
 }
})
```

My way of solving it, is checking the state of each element before disabling or enbabling, thus not trying to disable and already disabled element nor enable an already enabled element.
Is there a cleaner/simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with `emitEvent: false`

```
this.myForm.get('inputY').disable({emitEvent: false});
```